# Delete entry from database with WinJS and OData

Tags: odata, winjs

I'm trying to delete an entry from the database by odata. I get the error message

{"error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Bad Request - Error in query syntax."}}}

my code:

```
function deleteMonthEntry() {

    var item = actMonthEntries.getItem(listIndex);
    var queryString = "Stundens(" + item.data.datensatz_id + ")?$format=json";
    var requestUrl = serviceUrl + queryString;

    WinJS.xhr({
        type: "delete",
        url: requestUrl,
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        }
    }).done(
          function complete(response) {

          },
          function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          }
       );
}
```

My request URL looks like this:

```
    requestUrl = "http://localhost:51893/TimeSheetWebservice.svc/Stundens(305233)?$format=json"
```

Thanks
Marlowe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least I found the solution:

I've entered an filter request to my service like this:

TimeSheetWebservice.svc/Stundens?$filter=datensatz_id eq 305221

this returned the correct entry with this link:

TimeSheetWebservice.svc/Stundens(305221M)

So if I enter a M after the ID, everything works fin. But I have no idea where this M comes from.

Can anyone tell me the reason for this M? It does not belong to the ID. The ID is this
305221

Marlowe

Comment: Glad you got it to work! The datatype of your `datensatz_id` field is Edm.Decimal, and so adding an 'M' suffix to the number makes the key value a decimal instead of an Int32.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the server you're talking to supports the `$format` query option? Many don't. I would try removing that part of the request URI, and instead modify your `headers` value to specify an Accept header:

```
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}
```

For servers where `$format` is allowed, giving it a `json` value is equivalent to providing an Accept header with the `application/json` MIME type.

In general, for a `DELETE` operation, the `Accept` header or `$format` value only matters for error cases. With a successful `DELETE`, the response payload body will be empty, so there's no need for the server to know about your format preference.

Comment: The problem still the same, also the error message. I think the link creates the problem. In Fiddler the link in the raw view seems to end before the last ). But even if I enter the URL http://localhost:51893/TimeSheetWebservice.svc/Stundens(305231) in a browser, I get the same bad request error.

Comment: Hmm.. What is the data type of the key property used for `Stundens`? If it's an Int64, for example, it would need to be like this: `Stundens('305231')`

Comment: I've tried Stundens('305231') allready, but the same effect. It seems the entity framework of my OData service can not find the id given. How can I set this to the OData service in the entity framework?